# vi: s: change K_KP4:"4", into myvars.setvar(K_KP4,"4")

Tags: regex, vi

I really though I had it when I tried `s/^\(K_.+\):\("."\),/myvars\.setvar(\1,\2)/g`

I have a 100 lines or so like `K_KP4:"4"` that I want to change

I think the problem is \1 \2 refer to different instances of the same grouping pattern, which means ID'ing 2 different groups in a vi regex is impossible???

no luck with sed

isn't there a way of having a name capturing group, something like a=>(K_.+) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vi(m) regex, you need to escape the `+` to make it act as a metacharacter.

```
:%s/^\(K_.\+\):\("."\)/myvars.setvar(\1,\2)/
```

Also, the `g` flag for `:s` means `Replace all instances on this line`.  If there is truly one instance per line, as your post suggests, then the `g` is unnecessary and you instead need to specify that the command should run on all lines in the file -- `:%s/...`

Comment: I thought the g worked in such a way as it looked forward and backward, as well as match every instance?

Comment: Nope.  Assuming you're using vim, see `:help find-replace` and `:help 10.3` for some more info.